# How to see the Javadoc after generating it in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc

I am able to generate the Javadoc on NetBeans by right clicking my project ad putting generate javadoc. This gives me a BUILD SUCCESS in the output. However, I can't see the html file.

All the answers I'm finding say to go to properties and under build there should be an output directory, but I can't find it. Also attemped to look through my files for a dist/javadoc but can't find that either.

Comment: If you are using Maven as the build tool, the default location for generated javadocs is `${project.build.directory}/apidocs`.   If you are using Gradle it is `${project.docsDir}/javadoc`.   These can be changed in the respective build files. If you still can't find it, use the `find` shell command (or your OS's equivalent) to search the projects for `index.html` files.

Comment: Assuming you are building a Maven project with no special configuration, and to elaborate on Stephen's comment: when you _Generate Javadoc_ then in the **Output** window that is opened the first line will detail the call to **mvn.cmd** that is triggered. At the end of that line you should see _javadoc:javadoc_. The [Maven documentation for _javadoc:javadoc_](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html) specifies the default _<outputDirectory>_ for the javadocs. In my case that directory was **{project dir}/target/site/apidocs**. Do you not see that directory?